# "Could not find '' executable." after apt-get install/remove

Tags: apt, package-management

I get this message (Could not find '' executable.) in terminal after using sudo apt-get since I installed and removed Krusader. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove gstm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED: gstm
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
After this operation, 265 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 168039 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gstm ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
$ Could not find '' executable.
```

$PATH:

```
echo $PATH 
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin‌​:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: Please, could you paste the exact command you are typing and the exact output you are given? Also, could you paste the output of `echo $PATH`? Thanks!

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: the "funny" part is, that the "Could not find" line gets there after the progress, the cursor stops to blink for a second, and after that the line is printed to the terminal. this occured a lot of times while autoremoving kde packages after the uninstallation of krusader and kde-runtime.

Comment: @d3relict The information you've provided in comments should go in your question itself, as it's very hard to read in comments. (Some of it has been edited into your question...but it appears that some of it has not.)

Comment: sorry, I did not realize I can edit my question. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing some research, I found that string in the kdelibs-bin package. Try removing it:

```
sudo apt-get remove kdelibs-bin
```

Note that, if you have other KDE packages installed, this solution is not for you, because kdelibs-bin might be a dependency of these packages.

After that, kill all kdeinit4 instances (that is the program that gives you the error):

```
killall kdeinit4
```

Comment: I tried, but this package is not installed. However, the problem seems to have sorted out itself, after closing that terminal (and logging out) I receive no more of the above mentioned error. It was curious that before logging out, I received "Could not find '' executable." even after a simple "ls" command, not just after apt-get.

Comment: Here's an explanation: kdelibs-bin ships a program, kdeinit4, which runs in background. When removing kdelibs-bin, kdeinit4 was not stopped. It was stopped on log out.